# C# How to Remove leading 0's from 32bit int

Tags: c#, binary, int, trim, 32-bit

I ran into this question when watching the twit.tv show coding 101 (episode 2).  The code was pre written, but we were asked to change it in order to print out all the values of the while loop that converted an integer to a binary number.

I was able to print out everything with a simple "Console.WriteLine(number);" line.  When doing so, it returns all the values for the 32-bit int 0's included.

My question, is there a way to trim or remove all the extra 0's in the division of the loop (not in the final binary number) so they are not printed?  Here is the code of the program:

```
public static string ConvertIntToBinary(int number)
{
    int bits = (sizeof(int) * 16); //32bits
    char[] result = new char[bits]; //Array to hold the binary numbers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

    while (bits > 0)
    {
        bits = bits - 1;
        int remainder = number % 2; //% called mod or modulo which computes the remainder after dividing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

        if (remainder == 1) //If remainder is 1, store it as 1
            result[bits] = '1';
        else
            result[bits] = '0'; //Otherwise store it as 0

        number = number / 2; //Take the original number, divide it by 2
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    return new string(result).TrimStart('0'); //return the result as a string ,removing extra 0's
}
```

Comment: `C# How to Remove leading 0's from 32bit int` - an `int` does not have any leading zeros. It's just an integer value.

Comment: @HighCore Did you read the actual question or just the title?

Comment: @Andy just the title. That's what I do all the time. I'm too lazy to read the rest

Comment: @Andy in his defence it was quite hard to get what was meant

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I didn't understand at first either but then I read through the code.

Comment: I'm new to this, so forgive me if I explained it wrong.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `int bits = (sizeof(int) * 16); //32bits`  <- Is this right? Doesn't `sizeof()` return #bytes with are 8 bits not 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminate the loop when `number` reaches `0`. At that point there are no more non-zero bits to pull off:

```
public static string ConvertIntToBinary(uint value)
{
    int totalbits = sizeof(int) * 8;
    char[] result = new char[totalbits];
    int bits = totalbits;
    uint number = value;

    while (bits > 0)
    {
        bits--;
        uint remainder = number % 2;
        result[bits] = remainder == 0 ? '0' : '1';
        number /= 2;
        if (number == 0)
            break;
    }
    return new string(result, bits, totalbits - bits);
}
```

I fixed an error in the code: there are 8 bits in a byte, and not 16 as per your code. I also simplified a few parts of the code. I used a conditional expression which is more concise than the `if`. And I introduced another local variable to hold the working value to avoid modifying the actual parameter. This is generally good practise that makes debugging easier. I also used `uint` for the input parameter since the entire approach depends on the value being positive.

Note that the termination is inside the loop rather than in the `while` test. If you test for `number` equal to `0` in the while condition then you will end up returning the empty string for an input of `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation here.  I didn't initially write the code.  It was provided by a programmer to teach at a beginner level but I think I understand what you have done to make this a bit more efficient/better.  Beginner code typically doesn'

Comment: @AustinHarris I was updating as you posted!

Comment: @AustinHarris Of course, your answer doesn't work with numbers > 2^31-1  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You must of copied it in the middle of when I was posting a refactoring where I had an extra -1 on the line where var bits was being declared. It currently works with int32.maxValue, and int32.minValue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you could of made yours work with negative values if you just Cast the input as UInt instead of requiring the input to be UInt.

Comment: @Austin Indeed. Given that there is no official spec I'm going to follow my own spec chosen for maximum convenience to me!

Comment: David, thank you for helping out here.  I think I understand what you have done to change the code and make it more efficient.  Beginner code typically doesn't initially teach the most efficient and effective way of doing something.  Not sure why the initial byte was defined as 16? The code was pretty much written for us except for the final Console.WriteLine(number);

I tested the code and it works exactly how I wanted it to work.  I am still learning syntax of C# so I'm a bit unfamiliar with how everything works.  I'm going to keep learning and looking it over.  Again,thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore all the Zero bits as you loop until you hit a '1' bit.

This works with negative numbers as well.

```
    public static string ConvertIntToBinary(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0) return "0";
        var bits = (sizeof(int) * 8); // 8bits per byte
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var print = false;
        var mask = (uint)(1 << bits - 1);
        while (bits-->0)
        {
            var bit = (number & mask) == mask;
            if (bit) print = true;
            if (print) sb.Append(bit ? '1' : '0');
            mask = mask >> 1;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```